# Change Price of Rental Property Listing

Tags: rental-property

I had a Zillow listing, but after some applications and talks with some local folk, I’ve realized I severely underpriced the rental property. Is it legal to change the price ?

Comment: This is money, not law.

Comment: Laws vary by region, but if you've taken applications it feels like a crappy thing to do even if legal.

Comment: What do the terms and conditions for Zillow say?

Comment: If you're not bound to any **accepted** applications then I assume you can delete the listing and re-list it higher.

Comment: @Robert Longson what one can legally do in forming a particular kind of contract is absolutely a matter of law and on-topic here.

Answer (score 5):

You can change the rental price any time before there is an agreement with a particular rental applicant to rent the property at a particular price. Simply  applying to rent property listed at a particular price does not result in a binding agreement to rent the property at that price.

Answer (score 0):

An online listing such as Zillow represents an "offer". Offers can be revoked or modified at any time before someone "accepts" an offer. After acceptance, it is a "contract". ([More information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offer_and_acceptance))

Comment: An online listing such as Zillow is not an "offer". It is an invitation to make an offer. It cannot simply be accepted and result in a binding contract.